# How to use #element_validate and #value_callback in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, forms

I have followed the official Form API Documentation, but this code don't work for me on Drupal 8:

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['upload'] = array(
      '#title' => t('Upload Images'),
      '#type' => 'managed_file',
      '#upload_location' => 'public://image_example_images/',
      '#element_validate' => array('file_generic_settings_max_filesize'),
    );
    return $form;
  }

  private function file_generic_settings_max_filesize($element, &$form_state) {
    form_error($element, 'This is an error.');
  }
```

I have trying to remplace form_error() by $form_state->setErrorByName() but same problem, the file is uploaded and the validation is not called.

Have you a solution please ? The documentation of #element_validate is outdated ?

My objective:
Upload a lot of images, use a custom validation and insert all images thumbnails inside a `<div class="preview"></div>` with a field for name each images.

Example:
[image]
(After upload, display thumbnails and title field for name all each images)

Else, after upload, for display Thumbnails and other field (title and description) for each image, I need to use #value_callback, #process, #attached (manage field/display with js after upload) or an other option please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

To use an instance method for `#element_validate`/`#value_callback` etc you need a [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). e.g.

```
$form['upload'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Upload Images'),
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#upload_location' => 'public://image_example_images/',
  '#element_validate' => array(
    array($this, 'file_generic_settings_max_filesize'),
  ),
);
```

You'll need to mark `file_generic_settings_max_filesize()` (which if you were being a stickler for standards should really be named `fileGenericSettingsMaxFilesize`) as `public` to accommodate, as your class won't be invoking the method.

Documentation for this is [ongoing](https://www.drupal.org/node/1985838), the change notice is [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1734540).

Comment: If it is a method on the form object, then array('::file_generic_settings_max_filesize') can be used, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2325875

Comment: I just added more details to the example in the change notice, and added the documentation issue as related to it.